# Jenkins git maven release - git push failed/updates were rejected

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

I am trying to implement Jenkins maven release with git. I followed [this](http://elizabetht.github.io/blog/2014/02/05/jenkins-release-upload/) guide but my release is failing with below error. It is complaining while pushing. I am using workspace cleanup plugin so every time it should take the fresh copy of project. I am not sure why am I getting this error.

I tried to add a pre step which will do the "`git fetch`" and "`git pull origin master`" but I am still getting the error. It seems it is creating the local repo somewhere else than jenkins workspace. Can someone point me to correct direction?

```
10:44:05 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.2:prepare (default-cli) on project test: Unable to commit files
10:44:05 [ERROR] Provider message:
10:44:05 [ERROR] The git-push command failed.
10:44:05 [ERROR] Command output:
10:44:05 [ERROR] To ssh://abc.example.com/test.git
10:44:05 [ERROR] ! [rejected]          master -> master (fetch first)
10:44:05 [ERROR] error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://gitlab@abc.example.com/test.git'
10:44:05 [ERROR] hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
10:44:05 [ERROR] hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
10:44:05 [ERROR] hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
10:44:05 [ERROR] hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
10:44:05 [ERROR] hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
10:44:05 [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: the problem is located here: `10:44:05 [ERROR] hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do`...

Comment: @khmarbaise, I know I will have to do a git pull but I don't know where. I am trying in the workspace directory but it is saying "Already Up To date".

Comment: I REALLY do not understand why I'm also having this issue.
Nothing has ever happened on the remote since checkout (it is a few seconds ago the maven release plugin pulled the branch).
It worked in the past for me for other projects, but I CANNOT use the maven release plugin in my current setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by creating a new jenkins job. Everything was working fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have remote commits done on the repo branch your release:prepare is about to update. As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38230361/6309), this is a communication issue with other contributors to the same repo.

Make sure your local repo is up-do-date (`git pull`), then launch your `mvn` command.

This [GitLab issue](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/getting-mvn-release-to-work-with-gitlab-ci/4904/14) also suggested:

> You could skip pushing back to master and just the commit with the new tag.
>
> Run
>
> ```
> mvn release:prepare release:perform -DpushChanges=false
> git push —tags
> ```
>
> Additional benefit: you do not spoil the master’s commit history with the two release-commits.
>   Of course now you need to bump your version somehow.
>   You could use the ci_pipeline_id approach via [inclusion of this plugin](https://github.com/1and1/ono-maven-shared/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: I already tried git pull but no changes are there in the workspace directory.

Comment: @user3847894 Try the mvn -X ... command, in order to have more logs: you need to check if this is the master `branch` which is involved.

Comment: Yes I already tried mvn -X to get the debug logs and it is using master branch only. While specifying scm I used git with branch as "*/master" and option of "checkout local branch as master"

Comment: @user3847894 OK. Can you confirm your `master` HEAD commit (`git rev-parse master`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9110527/6309) is the same commit as the one returned by `git ls-remote`?

Comment: @user3847894 Then the issue is not in your repo working tree (where everything is up-to-date), but in the Jenkins's one: try and select: "Delete workspace before build starts." in your Jenkins job, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/28728663/6309 (no need to cleanup after the job, just before)

Comment: "Delete workspace before build starts." option is also enabled. Let me try from start